# How to get struct field in C

Tags: c, struct

I have the code:

```
main() 
{
   typedef struct
   {
      int data;
   } Information;

   typedef Information *PtrInformation;

   typedef struct InformationListStruct *PtrInformationListStruct;

   typedef struct InformationListStruct
   {
      PtrInformationListStruct ptrNext;
      PtrInformation ptrInf;
   } PtrInformationListStructElement;

   //==============================

   PtrInformationListStruct list;
   list = (PtrInformationListStruct)malloc(sizeof(InformationListStruct));
   PtrInformation ptr = (*list).ptrInf;  // error !!!

}
```

The compiler throw the error:

- "ptrInf" is not a member of InformationListStruct, because the type is not yet defined in function main()

If I put this line:

```
typedef struct InformationListStruct *PtrInformationListStruct;
```

after this lines:

```
   typedef struct InformationListStruct
   {
      PtrInformationListStruct ptrNext;
      PtrInformation ptrInf;
   } PtrInformationListStructElement;
```

then other error appears:

- Type name expected in function main()
- Declaration missing ; in function main()

**How to get "ptrInf" correctly?**

Comment: Just a small remark: putting type definition in function body is not a really good pratice to me.

Comment: Do you get other errors? When you have a question about errors, it's always best to add _all_ the errors to the question, and preferably verbatim (i.e. copy-paste).

Comment: I am using Unix GCC and I see below errors
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:22:51: error: ‘InformationListStruct’ undeclared (first use in this function)
t.c:22:51: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You shouldn't cast `malloc()`'s return in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) Also, use `sizeof`, don't repeat the type name:

```
list = malloc(sizeof *list);
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It can work around the error, your solution does the same by adding the missing `struct` keyword to make the type name legal. My view is that *having* the type name there is almost always a bad idea; the above works as long as the definition of `list` works which it did in the question.

Comment: still the same error. I tried the code in gcc (under Linux) and it compiled without errors. It seems, that my Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 works bad.

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
 list = (PtrInformationListStruct)malloc(sizeof(struct InformationListStruct));
 //                                               |
 //                                          note struct keyword
```

or

```
 list = (PtrInformationListStruct)malloc(sizeof(PtrInformationListStructElement));
```

since you have a `typedef` for it.

Comment: OP seems to use C, not C++, so `malloc` is the good way to create a new memory object.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, try the both code snippets. But still see the first error.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, I didn`t use ideone before. I post the code without registration. The link is  http://ideone.com/0GX33

Comment: @hello_amigo the code you posted doesn't give a compiler error, as you see.

Answer (score 1):

Which Compiler are you using, in visual studio , your code is compiling successfully. Please avoid type definations inside the body of a function.

Comment: I use Borland Compiler (BCC55). I have to try visual studio

Comment: This should be a comment. Visual studio compiles C++ if you don't name your files `*.c`, and the code is C.

Comment: Well i dont have dat much reputation to add a comment so i posted it as an answer